# Expose abstract type as Q_PROPERTY to QML

Tags: c++, qt, qml, blackberry-10, qt4.8

I am using Qt 4.8 with BB10.

I defined a base interface for classes to implement:

```
class AbstractImageProcessor : public QObject
{
public:
    AbstractImageProcessor(QObject * parent) : QObject(parent) {}
    virtual QImage process(const QByteArray &data) = 0;
    virtual ~AbstractImageProcessor(){ }
};
```

One such implementation that I want usable from QML looks like this:

```
class WebImageProcessor : public AbstractImageProcessor
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(int maxHeight READ getMaxHeight WRITE setMaxHeight NOTIFY maxHeightChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(int maxWidth READ getMaxWidth WRITE setMaxWidth NOTIFY maxWidthChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(bool fit READ isFit NOTIFY fitChanged)
    public WebImageProcessor(QObject * parent = 0) : AbstractImageProcessor(parent) {}
    virtual ~WebImageProcessor() {}
    /* rest of code omitted */ 
};
```

I want to expose this ***AbstractImageProcessor*** as a property on another QML type:

```
class WebImageView : public bb::cascades::ImageView {
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(AbstractImageProcessor* processor READ getProcessor WRITE setProcessor NOTIFY processorChanged)
    WebImageView(bb::cascades::Container * parent) : bb::cascades::ImageView(parent)  {}
    virtual WebImageView() {}
    /* rest of code omitted */
};
```

So I register my custom types with QML

```
//application.cpp
qmlRegisterUncreatableType<AbstractImageProcessor>("foo.controls", 1, 0, "AbstractImageProcessor", ""); ;
qmlRegisterType<WebImageProcessor>("foo.controls", 1, 0, "WebImageProcessor");
qmlRegisterType<WebImageView>("foo.controls", 1, 0, "WebImageView");
```

How I want to use it in QML

```
//main.qml
import foo.controls 1.0
/* omitted containers */

WebImageView { 
  processor: WebImageProcessor {
     maxHeight: 500
     maxWidth: 300
  } 
  /* rest of properties omitted */
}
```

But once I launch my application it fails to parse the qml document.

*bb::cascades::QmlDocument: error when loading QML from:   QUrl( "asset:///main.qml" )

--- errors:  (asset:///main.qml:138:57: Cannot assign object to property) 
bb::cascades::QmlDocument:createRootObject document is not loaded or has errors, can't create root*

In fact if I hover over the WebImageProcessor class in the editor, it says:

*The super type of the component WebImageProcessor is unknown, some of its properties are not validated.*

Now the thing is that the for example the built in cascades ListView exposes an abstract type as a Q_PROPERTY:

[http://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/cascades/bb_*cascades*_listview.html#property-datamodel](http://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/cascades/bb__cascades__listview.html#property-datamodel)

Event inspecting the header files of bb::cascades::ListView and bb::cascades::DataModel gives me no other clues because it's done essentially the same way.

Could it be that I have to register the types in a different way? If so how?

If I use WebImageProcessor in the Q_PROPERTY instead of the AbstractImageProcessor then it works as expected, but I want to expose the abstract type, and given that cascades does it then it's definitely possible somehow

Thanks

Comment: Your AbstractImageProcessor declaration is lacking a Q_OBJECT macro.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld Thank you! I swear I had the macro there before, but it would keep failing anyway so I in the end I removed it accidentally. But I rebuilt my project from scratch and it works now after adding the macro.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld PS. You may want copy the answer so I'll be able to reward you with points :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your AbstractImageProcessor declaration is lacking a Q_OBJECT macro, which is necessary to export the class to QtQuick.